# Передача id при клике на картинку

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет!

Сделал на jquery так называемый счетчик кликов по картинке и показов.

Вот код JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.click').click(function(){
        var id = $('input[name=id]').val()
        $.get('response.php', {'click':true, 'id':id});
    });
    $('.hits').load(function(){
        var id = $('input[name=id]').val()
        $.get('response.php', {'hits':true, 'id':id});
    });
});
```

Картинки выводятся так:

```
<div class="show">
<a href="http://#" class="click" title="summer" target="_blank">
<img src="http://.../logo-girl-summer.png" class="hits" alt="summer">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="4">
</a>
</div>
```

Скрытым полем передаю id картинки.

Ну и все это дело при клике или показе передается в response.php и там обрабатывается.

Все работает, НО обнаружил баг, что если 2 картинки на одной странице, то на клики и показы реагирует только ВЕРХНЯЯ... Т.е. скрытое поле `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="4">` передает id верхней картинке при клике на любую из них. 
Как правильно сделать, чтобы по клику передавался свой id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
$(this).find('input[name=id]').val()
```

Comment: Благодарю! Для кликов работает отлично. А не подскажите, как для показов сделать?

Если дописать $(this).find('input[name=id]').val() к показам, то вообще не реагирует.

А так, как было var id = $('input[name=id]').val(), добавляет сразу 2 показа к одному id вместо того, чтобы по 1 показу на 2 id.

Comment: Что-нибудь типа эвента 
load().
Но именно показы лучше ловить прямо сервером.

<img src="http://.../logo-girl-summer.png" class="hits" alt="summer">

файл show_image.php получает через mod_reqrite название картинки

Отдает заголовок

    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    print(file_get_contents('ИМЯКАРТИНКИ'))

Comment: Ну а если уже на jquery остановиться,

я показы ловлю так:

    $('.hits').load(function(){
        var id = $('input[name=id]').val()
        $.get('response.php', {'hits':true, 'id':id});
    });

Есть способ определить именно свой id, к который указал в 
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="4"> ?

Comment: Да. 
    var arr_of_ids = $("input[name=id]").map(function() {
                 return $(this).val();
              }).get();

далее либо склеиваем через arr_of_ids.join(','); и отправляем строку
123,4,5

Либо отправляем массивом.